# App crashes when opens trying to download content?

Tags: android

Built an app that when opens downloads content from a website and fills the image and button with text. Checked over all the code and their are no errors, but when the app runs on a phone it crashes when app opens with an error of app stopped working. Can somebody please help?

Xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
- <GridLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
  <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_column="0" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_gravity="fill" android:id="@+id/imageView" /> 
  <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_row="1" android:layout_column="0" android:tag="0" android:text="" android:id="@+id/button" android:onClick="celebChosen" /> 
  <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_row="2" android:layout_column="0" android:tag="1" android:text="" android:id="@+id/button2" android:onClick="celebChosen" /> 
  <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_row="3" android:layout_column="0" android:tag="2" android:text="" android:id="@+id/button3" android:onClick="celebChosen" /> 
  <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_row="4" android:layout_column="0" android:tag="3" android:text="" android:id="@+id/button4" android:onClick="celebChosen" /> 
  </GridLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA

```
package com.airrocketapps.matthillman.guessthecelebrity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> celebURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> celebNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    int chosenCeleb = 0;
    int locationOfCorrectAnswer = 0;
    String[] answers = new String[4];

    ImageView imageView;
    Button button0;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;

    public void celebChosen(View view) {

        if (view.getTag().toString().equals(Integer.toString(locationOfCorrectAnswer))) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong! It was " + celebNames.get(chosenCeleb), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        createNewQuestion();

    }

    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {


        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                return myBitmap;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }
    }


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {

                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        String result = null;

        try {

            result = task.execute("http://www.posh24.com/celebrities").get();

            String[] splitResult = result.split("<div class=\"sidebarContainer\">");

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img src=\"(.*?)\"");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);

            while (m.find()) {

                celebURLs.add(m.group(1));

            }

            p = Pattern.compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"");
            m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);

            while (m.find()) {

                celebNames.add(m.group(1));

            }


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        createNewQuestion();

    }

    public void createNewQuestion() {

        Random random = new Random();
        chosenCeleb = random.nextInt(celebURLs.size());

        ImageDownloader imageTask = new ImageDownloader();

        Bitmap celebImage;

        try {

            celebImage = imageTask.execute(celebURLs.get(chosenCeleb)).get();

            imageView.setImageBitmap(celebImage);

            locationOfCorrectAnswer = random.nextInt(4);

            int incorrectAnswerLocation;

            for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {

                if (i == locationOfCorrectAnswer) {

                    answers[i] = celebNames.get(chosenCeleb);

                } else {

                    incorrectAnswerLocation = random.nextInt(celebURLs.size());

                    while (incorrectAnswerLocation == chosenCeleb) {

                        incorrectAnswerLocation = random.nextInt(celebURLs.size());

                    }

                    answers[i] = celebNames.get(incorrectAnswerLocation);


                }


            }

            button0.setText(answers[0]);
            button1.setText(answers[1]);
            button2.setText(answers[2]);
            button3.setText(answers[3]);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your logs

Comment: Describe what's happening with your app in Activity Monitor, add crash logs OR try figuring this out for yourself by using debugger breakpoints, so that you can see what your app actually fetched from the web or whether it stores fetched data correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1):

```
imageTask.execute(celebURLs.get(chosenCeleb)).get()
```

This operation surely invokes `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Strict mode enabled in phone makes this Exception uncatchable. This is good, because makes you follow good programming guidelines. More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11749131/6507689)

The name `AsyncTask` specifies how the code should behave - asynchroniously. In your case you execute it synchroniously, you have to wait for the result to execute and pass it to activity through delegate.

Read the [`Usage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) section of Android Developer documentation.

Hint: inside onPostExecute method of `AsyncTask` invoke the code that should use the downloaded content.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner could you explain further